# Does WSO2 CEP with Esper engine support JMS Queues?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, esper

I want to send events to WSO2 CEP through ActiveMQ 'Queue'. Also i want to receive events in ActiveMQ 'Queue' processed by WSO2 CEP . I am wondering whether this is possible with Esper Engine ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Esper supports for jms queue, then you might achieve this, but we are not supporting for ESPER further (you can get more information [1]).. Sometimes you might need to write a custom broker to achieve this (Don't know exactly since I have not worked with jms queues)...

[1] http://dist.wso2.org/products/complex-event-processor/2.1.0/cep-release-notes.html

Thanks,

Mohan